# How to call a function from within an if-else statement?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, scope

I'm trying to call the pushChar function() within an if-else statement below it. The variable that I store the function in after execution is global, so why can't I call on it?

```
//Creates final array out of random characters from the arraypool that was created by the users criteria inputs.

function pushChar() {
    var randomPassword = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < pwLength; i++) {
        var item = passwordPool[Math.floor(Math.random() * passwordPool.length)];
        randomPassword.push(item);
    }
    return randomPassword;
}
var password = pushChar();


//validate that all of the conditions were met.

var checkUpper = (upperCaseChar.some(ele => password.includes(ele)))
var checkLower = (lowerCaseChar.some(ele => password.includes(ele)))
var checkNumeric = (numericChar.some(ele => password.includes(ele)))
var checkSpecial = (specialChar.some(ele => password.includes(ele)))

console.log(checkUpper);
console.log(checkLower);
console.log(checkNumeric);
console.log(checkSpecial);


if (checkUpper === confirmUpper &&
    checkLower === confirmLower &&
    checkNumeric === confirmSpecial &&
    checkSpecial === confirmNumber) {
    console.log(password);
} else {
    alert("somethings missing");
    pushChar(); //why won't this run??
}



//Presents randomly generated password to the user as a string. 
return password.join("");

}
```

Comment: It's because you have an extra closing curly bracket at line 8 when there's already one that closes the for-loop at line 6. Please consider fixing your code's indents such that these trivial mistakes can be easily noticed.

Comment: @Edric While I'm not a javascript pro, I don't think there's an extra } there; I think that is closing the function, as desired (and everything after it is not part of that function) - I think there's some missing code *before* the function, or somewhere else, though.

Comment: Welcome!
I'm joining the others + making a suggestion:
Use proper indentation = easier to read and understand and catch such errors as extra/missing closing curly brackets/etc.

Comment: I wasn't sure that I needed to add all of the code since it was only after that function I was concerned about. I didn't think my formatting was that off either, I'm very new to this so still learning though. Thanks for the advice on the formatting but any advice on the issue?

Comment: `pwLength` is undefined when `pushChar` is called, so the loop doesn't run,
so `password` gets an empty array `randomPassword = []` that is returned from `pushChar`.
Also, as mentioned in the comments, problem with block closures (that can be minimized with consistent indentation, again).